# PHP link with SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, hyperlink

New to PHP here. I'm working on a basic PHP project for university. I have a page with a list of patients. When you click on the patient it will take you to the patient page with more details of that patient.

I have a main patientDetails.php page which will display the details.

However I am a little puzzled. How do I get the "?Name.." part of the link to work. So how do I get the patientDetails page to load the specific patient details?

I have an index.php page which has the list of patients as below.

```
<td><a href="patientDetails.php?Name=Stuart">Stuart</a></td></tr><tr>    <td>2</td>
   <td><a href="patientDetails.php?Name=Fred">Fred</a></td></tr><tr>
```

In the PatientDetails page I have a select statement to gather details from the Database but not sure where else to go from here.

```
   $query = sprintf("select * from PHPEnrolment WHERE PatID = '$PatID' AND NAME     = '$Name' AND Email = '$Email'");
 $result = mysql_query($query, $link);
    if ($result) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  }
```

As you can see above the database table with patients has the PatID, Name and Email field.

Thanks

PLEASE NOTE: This is a basic project that I am working on, so I am aware some of the features are outdated but I need to get it working with these features if possible.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: the stuff in your `?Name=` part of the url is in `$_GET['Name']`

Comment: use $name = $_GET['Name']

Comment: Pamblam, how would I implement this exactly so that when I click on the link for Stuart example, it would display his details? Thanks

Comment: After all these years and people still come here with deprecated mysql questions, sigh........

Comment: user, you have much more important things to worry about right now (see tadman's comment) fix those and ask again. i'm sure you don't want to get sued by making confidential patient info public, or by your employer for exposing a dangerous 'bug'. don't skip his advice, it's important.

Comment: If you have more than one "Stuart" in your database, your search is not unique. You should use a unique search key, like userID or e-mail. And your PHP page definitely needs to retrieve the parameter with $_GET['']

Comment: Hi there Pam, this is just a basic university project. I just need to know how to get these links working with the database. Thanks

Comment: Tell your professor that he is teaching deprecated MySQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code there are several errors. and for getting value you can use `$_GET['Name']`. I am assuming that you have all other variables`($Email and $PatID)`

```
$Name = $_GET['Name'];
```

Your query is not right. Change it from

```
select * from PHPEnrolment WHERE PatID = '$PatID' AND $NAME = 'Name' AND Email $Email
```

To

```
select * from PHPEnrolment WHERE PatID = '$PatID' AND NAME = '$Name' AND Email = '$Email'
```

So your whole code should look like.

```
$query = "select * from PHPEnrolment WHERE PatID = '$PatID' AND NAME = '$Name' AND Email = '$Email'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
```

**NOTE : STOP USING `MYSQL`. It is deprecated now.**

Comment: Hi sorry I am new to PHP. Where/How would I implement this exactly?

Comment: You need to read a little on PHP, get familiar with it, and try things. This is not a recipe book... Documentation to start: http://php.net/manual/en/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url variables using $_GET. I see that you are passing only Name parameter in the url. Use the below code.

```
$name = $_GET['Name'];

$query = "select * from PHPEnrolment WHERE NAME = '$name'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);

if ($result) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     // display details here
  }
}
```